Add row groups to table visual
I am relatively new to power bi and I am curious if it is possible to create a table visual where I can display one value in one column for multiple values in different columns.
For example, given a dataset like this:
  Counterparty Commodity DealType   StartDate  FloatPrice  MTMValue
0           foo       bar      Buy  07/01/2024       18.73        10
1          fizz       bar      Buy  09/01/2024       17.12        10
2          fizz       bar      Buy  10/01/2024       17.76        10
3          fizz       bar      Buy  11/01/2024       18.72        10
4          fizz       bar      Buy  12/01/2024       19.47        10
5           foo   ab cred      Buy  01/01/2025       20.26        10
6           boo       baz     Sell  01/01/2025       21.04        10
6           boo       baz     Sell  01/01/2025       22.23        10
7          fizz       baz     Sell  01/01/2025       11.89        10
7          fizz       baz     Sell  01/01/2025       12.33        10
8           foo       baz     Sell  01/01/2025       14.78        10
8           foo       baz     Sell  01/01/2025       18.23        10
9           boo      rins     Sell  01/01/2025       16.43        10
10          boo   ab cred     Sell  01/01/2025       12.21        10

I would like to display the visual like this:
                       
Counterparty Commodity DealType   StartDate  MTMValue  FloatPrice
fizz         bar            Buy  09/01/2024        10       17.12
             bar            Buy  10/01/2024        10       17.76
             bar            Buy  11/01/2024        10       18.72
             bar            Buy  12/01/2024        10       19.47
foo          bar            Buy  07/01/2024        10       18.73

---------------------------------------------------------------------

fizz         baz            Sell  01/01/2025        10       11.89
             baz            Sell  01/01/2025        10       12.33
foo          baz            Sell  01/01/2025        10       14.78
             baz            Sell  01/01/2025        10       18.23
boo          baz            Sell  01/01/2025        10       21.04
             baz            Sell  01/01/2025        10       22.23

---------------------------------------------------------------------

foo          ab cred        Sell  01/01/2025        10       20.26
boo          ab cred        Sell  01/01/2025        10       12.21 

---------------------------------------------------------------------

boo           rins          Sell  01/01/2025        10       16.43


This is in an effort to reduce redundancy and provide more concise visuals. Is this possible to do in power bi?
One of my visuals is already a matrix that looks like this:
Counterparty  ab cred   bar   baz  rins
0          boo     10.0   0.0  10.0  10.0
1         fizz      0.0  40.0  10.0   0.0
2          foo     10.0  10.0  10.0   0.0


Have you tried the matrix visual?

I think you can try to use a matrix visual
enter link description here
maybe you can try to create a column
Column = Year('Table'[StartDate])&" "&'Table'[Commodity]

then use matrix to display


Although it does fit the criteria, I do not want to use the Commodity the column values because as my data grows displaying each commodity as a column would not be ideal

could you pls provide more sample data? I can't get the point that displaying each commodity as a column would not be ideal.

I will update the question. My sample at the moment only include 2 different commodities. This can increase to 10+. I also need the ability to add extra columns to the visual, which a matrix would not satisfy for me.
